# Boost function: store any function returned by boost::bind?

Tags: c++, function, boost

I want to write an asynchronous timer that calls a function after a certain amount of time has passed. Now I want to be able to bind a function using `boost::bind()` with any signature that the timer calls after a certain interval has passed. The way I do it right now is inspired by boost thread which has sort of an abstract baseclass to store the threaded function. This is what I do:

```
        class TimedFunctionBase
        {
        public:
            virtual void call() = 0;
        };

        typedef std::shared_ptr<TimedFunctionBase> TimedFunctionBasePtr;

        template<class F>
        class TimedFunction : public TimedFunctionBase
        {
        public:
            TimedFunction(F _f):
            m_function(_f)
            {
            }

            void call()
            {
                m_function();
            }

        private:
            F m_function;
        };
```

Then, inside the timer function, I simply save the callback as follows:

```
MyAsyncTimer
{
private:
    TimedFunctionBasePtr m_callback;
};
```

and call it inside the timed function with

```
m_callback->call();
```

My question is actually pretty simple: Does boost already provide a mechanism to do this? After a long search I could not really find much and the internals of `boost::thread` also looked as if there is nothing predefined for this kind of use. Maybe `boost::function_base`? The docs say that you may not create it directly. Is there a boost way, or do I have to write these container classes myself?

Comment: I don't see how this is much different than just using a `boost::function<void()>` and using `boost::bind` to bind all the arguments to a callable entity (function, functor, etc.).  Since you are already familiar with `boost::bind`, what exactly are you looking for that is different?

Comment: I want to be able to bind a function with any signature, not just void(). That is the reason for the question.

Comment: @user300713:  A `boost::function<void()>` can hold any function object that can be called with no arguments and it ignores the return type (since it itself returns `void`), so you can store any function or function object that has all of its arguments bound to it.  Since you are calling `call()` with no arguments, presumably you've already bound all the arguments to the function object.

Comment: @moka : If that's real code, you ought to give `TimedFunctionBase` a `virtual` destructor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

boost::bind + boost::function is all you need. And IIRC, that's what thread does.

Comment: hmm so how can I declare a boost function with any signature?

Comment: the trick is that you dont bind "any signature", you have to go down to void() from void( whatever ) by usign bind to embed arguments into a nullary function object.

Comment: okay, I was missing that it's a different thing if the arguments are allready bound to the function object. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think boost::asio provides some mechanisms to do this, this [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer2.html) seems to be exactly what you want.